# include data in base64 before sending to webservice

Tags: angularjs, string, web-services, binary, base64

I am creating a web app in mvc-5 in which i want to convert (pdf,word,excel,images) into binary data and then insert the data into database

```
$scope.savefunction = function () {
            var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
                r = new FileReader();
            r.onloadend = function (e) {
                $scope.data = e.target.result;
                console.log($scope.data);
            }
            r.readAsBinaryString(f);
        }
```

this is my coding for converting the data into binary but when i am printing the data `console.log($scope.data);` the data is showing as follows

> f?±3-ÂÞ²]ÄTê¸2j)õ,l0/%b¬
>   ð¼Ñêz£¿§Å,  ¡   /û|f\Zþçæ?6ï!Y´_áo]Aó

a friend of mine said me to convert the data into base 64 before sending it to webservice, i want to convert this code into base 64 before sending this to webservice, please suggest me some code that can help it to convert the data into base 64

Comment: The [WindowBase64 API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64) contains utility methods to convert data to and from base64, a binary-to-text encoding scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use readAsDataURL instead of readAsBinaryString

```
$scope.savefunction = function () {
        var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
            r = new FileReader();
        r.onloadend = function (e) {
            $scope.data = e.target.result;
            console.log($scope.data);
        }
        r.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
```

Comment: but this is my code, what i need to do when i need to convert it into base64

Comment: what i need to print then??

Comment: you can print this console.log($scope.data);

Comment: data is coming in base 64?